# How to init ngCropper with a predefined cropping area?

Tags: angularjs, crop

How can I manually set a custom cropping area using [ngCropper](https://github.com/koorgoo/ngCropper) ?

Answer (score 0):

The area is sent through the `option.data` property, you bind them to the modal using ng-options

```
<img ng-cropper ng-options="options">
```

Then the controller must define the option the following way:

```
$scope.options = {
    maximize: false, // very important otherwise it will overload the custom data
    data:{x: 261, y: 7, width: 56, height: 56} // those are arbitrary values
};
```

The data properties corresponds to the following:

[image]